# Elementor Pro Hover underline Animation only works on first element

Tags: css, elementor

I am working in Elementor Pro and using the custom css block. I am using the WpMenu Widget and inside I have the hover underline animation almost working perfectly with one issue. When I hover on the first item, an underline appears from left to right with a .35 second transition. When I unhover, the line animates again from left to right until it is no longer visible. Perfect. Now moving on to the second item in the list, the item underline animates left to right perfectly but when I unhover, the underline simply dissapears. This is the same for all the other item in the list (with the exception of the center item which won't get the underline as it will eventually be a logo). This is a sticky menu header and the colors are determined by its wrapper. I am not sure why the only item that this effect is working fully on is the first item. Any help appreciated. Here is the wrapper code followed by the menu code:

```
   /* Change the Background Colour on Scroll */
    .elementor-sticky--effects {
     background: #ffffff!important;
    }
    
    /* The scroll-logo is currently off.*/
    .scroll-logo {
     display: none;
    }
    
    /* Shut this logo off and activate the other logo after scroll*/
    .elementor-sticky--effects .scroll-logo {
     display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .elementor-sticky--effects .original-logo {
     display: none;
    }
    
    
    /* Change Text Colour and Links colour */
    
    .elementor-sticky--effects .menutextcolours ul li a {
     color: #34394B!important;
    }
    
    .elementor-sticky--effects .menutextcolours ul li.logocentral a {
        color: #ddab5d!important;
    }
```

Menu code

```
ul li a::after {
  content: '' !important;
  position: absolute !important;
  width: 70% !important;
  left: 15% !important;
  bottom: 10px !important;
  height: 0.15em !important;
  background: currentColor !important;
  border-radius: 5px !important;
  transform: scaleX(0) !important;
  transform-origin: bottom right !important;
  transition: transform 0.35s ease-in-out !important;
}

ul li a:hover::after {
  transform: scaleX(1) !important;
  transform-origin: bottom left !important;
}


.logocentral {
    margin-left: 200px!important;
    margin-right: 200px!important;
}

.logocentral a {
    font-family: "Badminton", Sans-serif!important;
    font-weight: 500!important;
    font-size: 62px!important;
color: #ddab5d!important;
    
}

selector .logocentral a::after {
    display: none!important;
}
```

Any help on this so I can learn why this isn't working as expected would be greatly appreciate. Thank you.
P.S. Please ignore the !importan peppered generously throughout. In Elementor Pro, If I don't add them, the code simply doesn't work at all. Thank you.